# Modify uid in ldap repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, openldap

I'm developping an application spring-boot for get user information on Ldap repository using LdapTemplate.

I use user email as uid, when a user update his email I have to update his uid too. The problem is that the methods below work for all Person fields but not for UID. I get an error:

```
LDAP: error code 64 - value of naming attribute 'uid' is not present in entry
```

This is a snippet:

```
public void updateUser(Person p) throws InvalidNameException {
    Name dn = buildDn(p);
    DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);
    LdapMapper.mapToContext(p, context);
    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
}
```

BuildDn:

```
public Name buildDn(Person p) throws InvalidNameException {
    List<Rdn> lstRdn = new ArrayList<Rdn>();
    lstRdn.add(new Rdn("dc", "priv"));
    lstRdn.add(new Rdn("dc", "com"));
    lstRdn.add(new Rdn("ou", "customers"));
    lstRdn.add(new Rdn("ou", "myusers");
    lstRdn.add(new Rdn("uid", "oldUid"));

    Name name = new LdapName(lstRdn);

    return name;
}
```

Mapper

```
public static void mapToContext(Person p, DirContextOperations context) {
    context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person", "inetOrgPerson", "organizationalPerson" });
    context.setAttributeValue("cn", p.getFirstName());
    context.setAttributeValue("sn", p.getLastName());
    context.setAttributeValue("mail", p.getEmail());
    context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", p.getPassword());
    context.setAttributeValue("uid", "NewUid");
}
```

Would you have any ideas to fix this bug ?

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

You can't do a Modify on the uid field, instead you will have to rename the record to update the uid.

Like so:

`ldapTemplate.rename("uid=oldUid,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com", "uid=newUid,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com")`

instead of

`ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);`.

Resource:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Define the configuratons  for LdapContextSource and LdapTemplate

Name dn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance().add("uid", uid).build();

Name dnNew = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance().add("uid", newUid).build();

ldapTemplate.rename(dn, dnNew);
```

This will update the uid.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html

```
void    rename(Name oldDn, Name newDn)
```

Move an entry in the LDAP tree to a new location.

Answer (score 0):

The *rename* Method of ldapTemplate works somehow, **but** how would I rename the attribute itself?:

```
  @Test(expected = SchemaViolationException.class)
  public void testModifyRdnUsingDirContext() {
      LdapName name = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance()
        .add("ou", "people")
        .add("uid", "test")
        .build();
      LdapName newName = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance()
        .add("ou", "people")
        .add("uid", "test1")
        .build();
      // seems disfuctional, because it is not possible to change the value
      // of the uid attribute to the new one beforehand or afterwards. This
      // problem might be unboundID (embedded ldap server) specific.
      ldapTemplate.rename(name, newName);
      DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(newName);
      context.setAttributeValue("uid", "test1");
      ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
    }
```